# Unity select Images and call method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-engine

I am making a game in Unity and I want to be able to switch between images. I want the images to do something when I press a button on my controller/keyboard. Also it should be possible to switch between them when using the joystick. I put a button on the image which should make it possible. The switch already works as I give the navigation on the button certain values. When switching the selection I want to activate UI elements (another image) that surround the button but I don't know how to do it. Do you guys have an idea?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so] it seems that what you are looking for is a general tutorial for Unity. This question doesn't really fit the premise of this site. Try google for basic Unity tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GameObject.Find("OBJECT_NAME")` to get the reference to the `UI elements` that surround your button. And use `GameObject.SetActive(true)` to activate the `UI elements`.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
How would I call it? The navigation happens in the inspector

Comment: call `GameObject.Find("OBJECT_NAME")` in your `void Start( )` method in your script and use `GameObject.SetActive(true)`  in the same script wherever you need to do so in your game.

Comment: There are a lot of other options that are preferable over the expensive and error prone `Find` based on names though ...